# How to display an image after a time interval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, display

I want to display an image 3 seconds after the user has clicked the left mouse button.
Here's a part of my code:

```
pic=pygame.image.load('pic.png')
while True:
  for event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    screen.blit(pic,(100,100))
```

It is only displayed a moment. I tried using `for` and `while` loops, however, it stutters some seconds and then shows a flash.

I think that I can maybe use a timer, add 3s, like so:

```
for event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
  #get now time here,and assignment for timeclick
if timeclick+3s>=timenow:  # pseudocode
  screen.blit(pic,(100,100))
```

How can I write this code paragraph? And are there better ways?

Answer (score 2):

Start the timer when the user clicks a mouse button, then calculate the passed time in the main loop and if it's `>= 3`, blit the image.

```
import pygame as pg


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    font = pg.font.Font(None, 40)
    img = pg.Surface((100, 100))
    img.fill((190, 140, 50))
    click_time = 0
    passed_time = 0

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            # Start the timer.
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                click_time = pg.time.get_ticks()

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        if click_time != 0:  # If timer has been started.
            # Calculate the passed time since the click.
            passed_time = (pg.time.get_ticks()-click_time) / 1000

        # If 3 seconds have passed, blit the image.
        if passed_time >= 3:
            screen.blit(img, (50, 70))

        txt = font.render(str(passed_time), True, (80, 150, 200))
        screen.blit(txt, (50, 20))

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: Firstly thank you.But why do lots of people add sys.exit() in the end?I use only pygame.quit().Maybe they are the same.

Comment: I think I once read that on some systems closing the pygame window could be troublesome and `sys.exit` could help, but can't find a source. Maybe this is a relict from the past that isn't needed anymore. I need to investigate.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote! You can also [accept answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) which will give you 2 reputation points and 15 for the responder, but you don't have to.

Comment: Calling `sys.exit()` really seems to be a relict of the past which reportedly was useful for old Python and pygame versions. It looks like you can just omit it. `pygame.quit` is actually also not needed, except for people who run their games in the IDLE editor (it can't close the pygame window without `pygame.quit`). So if you want to be IDLE friendly you can leave it in.

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw the image in the main application loop. Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to return the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called. When the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event occurs, then calculate the point in time after that the image has to be displayed. Display the image after the current time is greater than the calculated point of time:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen= pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

#pic = pygame.image.load('pic.png')
pic = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
pic.fill((255, 255, 255))
pic_time = 0

run = True
while run:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pic_time = current_time + 3000 # 3000 milliseconds == 3 seconds

    screen.fill(0)

    if pic_time > 0 and current_time >= image_time:
        screen.blit(pic,(100,100))

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```